# angular.js passing function into an object

Tags: function, angularjs

I think it may be useful if I show the wider scope :) below is my html:

```
<div class="resSection2 rel">
                        <div class="proceed rel">
                        <div ng-repeat="record in records">
                        <div class="rel fptsans {{record.className()}}">Balkans<i class="icon-check icon-2x posIco"></i></div>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Key factor here is the {{record.className()}} binding which depending on its value determines the behaviour of the record, whether it gets a proper styling or not. as you can see it is a reference to a function. And here is the JS:

```
var antroApp = angular.module('antroApp', []);
$scope.records = [
    {id:0, 
    className: $scope.probieren,
    recordName:$scope.alpeic.length 

    },
    {id:1,
    className: $scope.probieren,
    recordName:$scope.alpeic.length 

    }

    ];

$scope.probieren = function(){
    if($scope.records.recordName > 10){
        $scope.records.className == 'special'
    }
    else{
        $scope.records.className == 'normal'
    }
}   
}
antroApp.controller('dialogWindows', dialogWindows);
```

When I set up the className statically ("special" or "normal") it renders perfectly 
but when it comes to a function, it all just gets stuck. really feel helpless about this. any tips appreciated.

Comment: `className` should be a function or return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You've set it up fine except they have to be defined in the other order, but in your dom when you use it call a function like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="record in records">
    <div class="{{ record.className() }}">{{ record.recordName }}</div>
</div>
```

There's a few more issues with how you're referencing $scope.records.className instead of some index of the array for records but my answer should answer the specific question you have.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your way but it doesn't work. I've completed the question with the html, which might ease to figure out what is actually happening here.

Comment: You have logical errors outside the scope of this question see here:

 $scope.records.className == 'normal'

It should be something like  $scope.records[SOME_INDEX].className == 'normal'